# How to maintain aspect ratio when resizing PaintCode generated view?

Tags: ios, xamarin, paintcode

I'm using **PaintCode** to generate a stylekit for my xamarin.ios app. I have a simple logo that I pasted into PaintCode from illustrator. Everything looks fine, I have a frame and the generated draw method takes a rect.

At one point I had it resizing in my storyboard but it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio so obviously the logo looked wrong depending on the size of the UIView.

How can I add variables/expressions to paintcode so that the generated code automatically maintains the aspect ratio when the UIView is resized?

Thanks.

Comment: Autolayout aspect ratio constraint ?

Comment: No, this is specific to Paintcode (paintcodeapp.com). Paintcode generates a drawing method for vector assets but by default it does not maintain aspect ratio, I assume this needs to be implemented manually but I'm not sure how.

Comment: it's a UIView so you can setup constraints I guess

Answer (score 7):

This is possible with **Variables**. Try creating two Variables like this:

1. Numeric *“Width”* with a value for example `100`.
2. Expression *“Height”* with a value `width / 2`. This would maintain a ratio of 2:1, change as you need.

Then attach these two to your Frame object on Width and Height attributes. After that, the generated method will take only one numeric parameter – the `Width`:

```
- (void)drawMyCanvasWithWidth: (CGFloat)width;
```

Should look like on this image:

[image: Preview]

Then just pass your desired width and the height will be calculated automatically.

---

It would also be possible to maintain `CGRect` parameter of the method and to find fitting rectangle using Variables. I’ll add that if you ask.

Comment: Yeah, this is sort of what I came up with. I setup variables for expressions for aspect ratio and then used those to generate an adjusted height and set that to be the height of my frame. But, I need to refine it so that it works either way whether the height or width is the pinned value. Your code pins the width but if you make a UIView and change the height you can clip the image. I want it so that if the height would clip the image then the height is then used as the pinned value and we generate a width. I think this is possible with an expression that uses makeRect() in paintcode.

Comment: Ok so this worked, I have a Rect variable that is set to the size of the canvas. Then I have a variable for the aspect ratio that uses constants. Then I created an expression that had this: `logoMarkFrame.height < (logoMarkFrame.width/logoMarkAspectRatio)
?
makeRect(0,0,logoMarkFrame.height*logoMarkAspectRatio,logoMarkFrame.height)
:
makeRect(0,0,logoMarkFrame.width,logoMarkFrame.width/logoMarkAspectRatio)` Then connect that to the frame in my canvas and it works fine. The next step I think would be keeping it centered when the height is smaller than the width/ar.